# Почему вызывается деструктор?

Tags: c++, vector

```
std::vector<ft_bitmap> bitmap;
 for (uint32_t char_code = GLYPH_START; char_code < GLYPH_END; char_code++)
    {
        // Load text bitmap
        GetBitmap(&bitmap_text, font, nullptr, ft_font, char_code);

        if (bitmap_text.buffer)
        {
            bitmap.emplace_back(bitmap_text);

        }
    }
```

*bitmap.emplace_back(bitmap_text);* Во время исполнения вызывается деструктор при использовании вектора, из-за чего это может быть?

```
struct ft_bitmap
{
    ~ft_bitmap()
    {
        if (buffer)
        {
            delete buffer;
            buffer = nullptr;
        }
    }

    uint32_t width = 0;
    uint32_t height = 0;
    unsigned char pixel_mode = 0;
    unsigned char* buffer = nullptr;
};
```

Comment: Например, из-за увеличения буфера и переноса имеющихся элементов?

Comment: из-за нехватки памяти и переноса элементов на другой участок памяти.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Когда буфер в векторе расширяется, выделяется новая память и элементы переносятся на новое место, на старом месте они уничтожаются.

Попробуйте вызвать

```
bitmap.reserve()
```

с достаточным количеством элементов — при этом проблема должна исчезнуть.

Вот, сравните два кода и результаты их выполнения:

https://ideone.com/un0X9A и https://ideone.com/DXJAHU

Comment: Да, работает, я раньше пытался использовать метод .resize, оказывается он не так работает, как я думал :)

Comment: У меня еще появился вопрос: а как правильно потом передать эти данные в функцию? Ведь тогда, если я передам их, они передадутся по ссылке, вызовется деструктор в функции, а потом в конце области видимости функции, где цикл

Comment: Не понял вопрос. Почему вызовется деструктор в функции? Приведите пример кода с пояснениями, где по-вашему вызывается деструктор...